# How to create an environment variable in bash using Node and let the variable alive after program execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, shelljs

I have a node program called `xapp` that runs in console. I would like `xapp` create a environment variable that stay alive until user close the terminal (not only while the program is running).

I tried this so far:

```
let key = 'bacon';
let MYVAR = 'AWESOME_VAR';
shell.exec(`export ${MYVAR}=${key}`);
shell.exec(`echo \$${MYVAR}`);
```

This doesn't print anything in console.

but even if 'bacon' is showed, what I really want is that the environment var stay alive after `xapp` finish... So I could execute this in terminal:

```
echo $AWESOME_VAR
```

and see him showing 'bacon'.

What I'm trying to do is to get `xpat` to communicate through multiple executions, but only while the same terminal session is active.

I tried something using `process.env` without success, since the environment variables is valid only in the same process.

Comment: I think you are looking for the [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(command)) command. Write your environment vars to a file, the next time around shell.exec source with your filename and they should be available in process.env.

Comment: it's a good solution. thanks

Comment: it doesn't work cause shelljs does't recognize the source command. So I tried to put the source into a sh file and execute it via shell.exec and it doesn't work too. Even if it executes the script, the var is not changed.

Comment: nevermind.. i get it to work using dotenv extension and writing the var in a .env file.